# Spring Data Rest Assocation Excerpt

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have a resource A which has a @OneToMany association with resource B. At the same time, the repository of B is configured with `excerptProjection`.

As a result, every time I want to get the a list of A, the association resources of B is fetched which would do some unwanted query to slow down the whole request. Even if I explicitly specify a projection of A which does't contain the get method of association resources of B. Though the result JSON does't contain association resources, the query still get executed.

I digged into the problem. I found if a association is configured with `excerptProjection`. The value would be fetched whether they will appear in the final result.

Beblow are the related codes of PersistentEntityResourceAssembler#getEmbeddedResources

```
entity.doWithAssociations(new SimpleAssociationHandler() {

            /*
             * (non-Javadoc)
             * @see org.springframework.data.mapping.SimpleAssociationHandler#doWithAssociation(org.springframework.data.mapping.Association)
             */
            @Override
            public void doWithAssociation(Association<? extends PersistentProperty<?>> association) {

                PersistentProperty<?> property = association.getInverse();

                if (!associationLinks.isLinkableAssociation(property)) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!projector.hasExcerptProjection(property.getActualType())) {
                    return;
                }

                Object value = accessor.getProperty(association.getInverse());

                if (value == null) {
                    return;
                }

                ...
```

Is this designed to be like this? Are there any work around?